# How to restore from 429 Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota)

Tags: google-people-api

my questions are simple, I am using PEOPLE API and I have skipped the quota limit for one of the users using the API, the error is only shown when trying to create a new contact for this specific user.

The error says code: 429, message: Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota).

1. How can I restore the user to use the API again?
2. If the limits are reset every minute, how is it possible that after 3 days the user is still blocked?

I do not want to increase the quota, what I want is to restore the quota again.
Additionally to this in my developer panel there is no indication that I have exceeded the quota which for PEOPLE API is limited to 90 per minute.

**My code is:**

```
const request = {
    requestBody: contact
}

service.people.createContact(request)
                        .then((res)=>{
                            console.log('Done to create a contact', res.data);
                        })
                        .catch((err)=>{
                            console.log('Error', err);
                        })
```

**And the retuning massage is:**

```
response: {
config: {
  url: 'https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people:createContact',
  method: 'POST',
  paramsSerializer: [Function],
  data: [Object],
  headers: [Object],
  params: [Object: null prototype] {},
  validateStatus: [Function],
  body: '{"names":[{"familyName":"PASIEGA","givenName":"HOTEL","middleName":"VILLA","unstructuredName":"HOTEL VILLA PASIEGA"}],"addresses":[{"type":"home","streetAddress":"LAS BARRERAS, SN","city":"HOZNAYO","region":"S","postalCode":"39716","country":"ESPAÑA","countryCode":"ES"}],"emailAddresses":[{"value":"reservas@grupolospasiegos.com","type":"work"}],"phoneNumbers":[{"value":"785 52 12 58","type":"Villa Pasiega"},{"value":"785 52 12 58","type":"workFax"}],"biographies":[{"value":"Hotel los Pasiegos - Grupoo los Pasiegos","contentType":"TEXT_PLAIN"}],"urls":[{"value":"http://grupolospasiegos.com/contacto/","type":"profile"}],"organizations":[{"type":"Other","name":"HOTEL VILLA PASIEGA","title":"RESERVA"}],"memberships":[{"contactGroupMembership":{"contactGroupResourceName":"contactGroups/199bb8970e07b6a8"}},{"contactGroupMembership":{"contactGroupResourceName":"contactGroups/55fdbf598e048c03"}},{"contactGroupMembership":{"contactGroupResourceName":"contactGroups/5ee644148f02b901"}}]}',
  responseType: 'json'
},
data: { error: [Object] },
headers: {
  'alt-svc': 'h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"',
  'cache-control': 'private',
  connection: 'close',
  'content-encoding': 'gzip',
  'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
  date: 'Thu, 22 Oct 2020 12:47:16 GMT',
  server: 'ESF',
  'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
  vary: 'Origin, X-Origin, Referer',
  'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
  'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
  'x-xss-protection': '0'
},
status: 429,
statusText: 'Too Many Requests'


},config: {
url: 'https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people:createContact',
method: 'POST',
paramsSerializer: [Function],
data: {
  names: [Array],
  addresses: [Array],
  emailAddresses: [Array],
  phoneNumbers: [Array],
  biographies: [Array],
  urls: [Array],
  organizations: [Array],
  memberships: [Array]
},
headers: {
  'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip',
  'User-Agent': 'google-api-nodejs-client/0.7.2 (gzip)',
  Authorization: 'Bearer ya29.a0AfH6SMAJtuUp3vLhSXlDVyAd80iQc1D-mYZUD7mENq12vTiegBAV834dTGYbpuuVN9wCpJ0JBB51oMwEozhb9_xoM7s9NTiwqBicNYZAjzPpjLL4MvQUp8b-Oqju8opyNwDAJWCnLvUJ5Bvz266z5H1ZXIpe3_YstXDRzw',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  Accept: 'application/json'
},
params: [Object: null prototype] {},
validateStatus: [Function],
body: '{"names":[{"familyName":"PASIEGA","givenName":"HOTEL","middleName":"VILLA","unstructuredName":"HOTEL VILLA PASIEGA"}],"addresses":[{"type":"home","streetAddress":"LAS BARRERAS, SN","city":"HOZNAYO","region":"S","postalCode":"39716","country":"ESPAÑA","countryCode":"ES"}],"emailAddresses":[{"value":"reservas@grupolospasiegos.com","type":"work"}],"phoneNumbers":[{"value":"942 525 962","type":"Villa Pasiega"},{"value":"942 525 963","type":"workFax"}],"biographies":[{"value":"Hotel los Pasiegos - Grupoo los Pasiegos","contentType":"TEXT_PLAIN"}],"urls":[{"value":"http://grupolospasiegos.com/contacto/","type":"profile"}],"organizations":[{"type":"Other","name":"HOTEL VILLA PASIEGA","title":"RESERVA"}],"memberships":[{"contactGroupMembership":{"contactGroupResourceName":"contactGroups/199bb8970e07b6a8"}},{"contactGroupMembership":{"contactGroupResourceName":"contactGroups/55fdbf598e048c03"}},{"contactGroupMembership":{"contactGroupResourceName":"contactGroups/5ee644148f02b901"}}]}',
responseType: 'json'
},
code: 429,
errors: [
{
  message: 'Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota).',
  domain: 'global',
  reason: 'rateLimitExceeded'
}
```

]
}

The image below you can see my developer google console and it shows that i only have used 25 createContact request in a period of 2 days with a 100% error message which is the message a post here.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KRz4.png)

**By the way thanks for your help.**

Comment: Can you confirm the quota hasn't been exceeded and is indeed for the request you are mentioning? How does your request look like?

Comment: I update my post, so you will be able to see, my error message, my code, and my google console. Thanks por your healp

Comment: Are you getting the data for the contact using another API perhaps?

Comment: No, the same API, for everything and every body. Just one People API for all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the **solution** to the problem and I have to be a bit extensive when explaining the solution.

Each google user has a limit on the number of contacts that can be stored in his contacts.google.com account, the limit is 25,000 contacts, if you exceed this limit the error shown in People API is 429 = *Too Many Requests*, my user only has 9000 contacts so the limit was not the cause of the problem, but what it had not considered is that a few weeks ago Google added a buttom basket for deleted contacts to contacts.google.com and it looks like that each contact deleted is stored and counted as a contact within contacts.google.com. This is what happened to me.

**In summary:**

My user has 9,000 visible contacts and 16,000 deleted contacts giving a total of 25,000 contacts causing error 429 to be displayed every time I try to create a new contact.

**Solution:**

Delete all deleted contacts, and everything should be resolved.

**Hope:**

Google allows access to People API to the contacts in the deleted basket and that error 429 better explains what it refers to cuz as i see in this case it is not a quota problem.

**Important:**

Thank you very much to @ale13 for your intent to help, I will leave this here in case future developers face the same problem.